PSPDFKit Electronic Signature Not Working in Production
With PSPDFKit https://pspdfkit.com/developers/, I have an electronic signature function added to my PDF viewer. My license supports electronic signatures, and the signature functionality functions flawlessly when using the local license on localhost. When the feature is put into production, though, it frequently stops working and the signature dialog never opens, with no issues in the console. Has anyone ever had this problem before or had a solution?
this is problem not happening with other apps like android and ios

you can read that https://pspdfkit.com/guides/web/pspdfkit-server/troubleshooting/license-troubleshooting/

Sadly, this doesn't fix my issue. The signature only functions occasionally, which is the issue
